# ColdFusion - Using the Query Output to Store Variables For Each Row to Re-Query for Edit

Tags: sql, forms, coldfusion, cfml

I am definitely a noob at CFML and have been trying to wrap my head around this for some time. I have my query output my data with a Detail button I created that will enter into a new page to edit the information. Each #INV# would have more line items associated to them for review. My goal is to click the button and run a query based off the INV for that given row to return output of all associated line items that need some sort of approval in a new page. Then giving me the ability to edit the data.

I think I need to be able to store the INV column as a variable in my code but am not sure how to accomplish this.

Sorry if it isn't too clear!

```
<cfquery name="Review" datasource="FINANCE_EQMT_ACCT"> 
    SELECT '1' as ROW, ''ABC CO.' AS OWNER, 'T1234567' AS INV, '50.00' AS TOTAL FROM TBL_TEST

</cfquery> 
<div class="container col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-md-push-1 col-lg-5 col-lg-push-1">   
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <legend>QUEUE</legend>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">#</th>
          <th>Owner</th>
                <th>Invoice</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th></th>
            </tr>
      </thead>        
        <tbody>
         <cfoutput query="Review"> 
            <tr>
              <td class="text-center">#ROW#</td>
              <td>#OWNER#</td>
                    <td>#INV#</td>
              <td>#TOTAL#</td>
              <td class="text-right"><form action="review_action.cfm" method="post"><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Detail"></form></td>
                </tr>
        </cfoutput>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to save it. You just need to push it over to the next page

```
...
<td class="text-right">
  <form action="review_action.cfm" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="INV" value="#INV#" />
     <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Detail">
  </form>
</td>
...
```

`review_action.cfm` will then process that value as a part of `form.inv`

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it. If you don't mind, may I ask where you learned CFML? I'm having a little difficulty in finding resources outside of Learn CF in a Week and Adobe.

Comment: See my profile to various sources. Stackoverflow is a great source too

Comment: Regarding Stackoverflow being a great source, trying to answer questions exposes you to other people's answers.  I've learned a lot of things that way over the years.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I'll see what I can contribute!